# how to use for/ while loop to write a filter function in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to write a loop function which returns True if all the element equals to 3, and return False otherwise. 
WITHOUT using the abstract function.

```
is_same([3,3,3,3,3]) => True
is_same([3,4,6]) => False
```

Comment: which abstract function is this? i know of no such thing in the standard library

Comment: well, idk which abstract function you're talking about but all those 3 solutions will work : `all(x==3 for x in your_list)`, `len(filter(lambda x: x!=3, your_list)) == 0`, `len(set(your_list)) == 1 and your_list[0] == 3`

Comment: Abstract function means filter, map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

```py
all(x == 3 for x in myList)
```